# How to prevent scrolling the whole page in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Haii I'm trying to prevent scrolling in mobile devices and ipad for desktop the scrolling is not occuring when I switch to mobile devices and ipad the scroll occured. The scrolling occured only in the mobile devices and ipad. Can anyone please help me to avoid the scrolling. Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

```
<v-card color="#1976D2" tile class="bg-color pa-0 px-2 mx-0" fluid>
    <v-container fill-height>
        <v-row class="pa-0" justify="center">
            <v-card flat color="#1976D2">
                <v-row class="mt-0" justify="left">
                    <v-avatar class="ml-5" style="background-color:#ffffff" size="70">
                        <v-img contain width="400" :height="$vuetify.breakpoint.lg
                || $vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly ? 150: 100" :src="`/img/syfol/logo.png`">
                        </v-img>
                    </v-avatar>
                </v-row>
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <div style="font-size:2em;" class="text-left white--text font-weight-bold">Syfol</div>
                    <div style="1em" class="white--text  text-left">Sign in
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-left  text-size">
                        <small class="mt-9 white--text text-size">Crack your complications with our Syfol
                            solution to get prevail in the field!
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="9">
                    <v-row justify="center">
                        <v-img contain width="400" :height="$vuetify.breakpoint.lg
                || $vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly ? 150: 200" :src="`/img/syfol/login-01.svg`"></v-img>
                    </v-row>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="12" class="pb-lg-0 pb-0 pb-xl-2">
                    <v-row justify="center">
                        <v-col cols="12">
                            <v-btn block title='Sign in using Microsoft' class="text-primary rounded-xl text-capitalize font-weight-bold body-2 px-2" color="white" @click="getSharepointUrl" :loading="loading">
                                <v-icon color="primary" class="mr-2"> mdi-microsoft </v-icon>
                                Sign in with Microsoft
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-col>
                <v-col class="pb-0 my-2" cols="12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <span class="white--text text-size text-size">follow us
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </v-col>
                <v-row class="mx-2  my-2" justify="center">
                    <v-col cols="3" md="2" sm="3" xl="2" xs="1" class="pa-0 pr-sm-1" lg="3" v-for="(item,index) in socialMedialLinks" :key="index">
                        <v-chip small style="fontSize:11px" class="ma-1" target="_blank" :href="item.link" text-color="white" :style="{backgroundColor:item.backgroundColor}">
                            <v-avatar class="ma-0  move-to-rightside" style="border:2px solid white !important">
                                <v-icon class="pa-1" color="white" style="font-size:15px;">{{ item.icon }}
                                </v-icon>
                            </v-avatar>
                            {{ item.text }}
                        </v-chip>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-col class="pa-0 ma-2" cols="12">
                    <v-row class="my-1" justify="center">
                        <div class="text-size footer mb-6 text-center white--text text-size">© {{ currentYear }},
                            Processdrive India Pvt. Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
                        </div>
                    </v-row>
                </v-col>
            </v-card>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-card>
    <style>
.bg-color {
    background-color: #1976D2;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed !important;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(253, 253, 253);
    text-align: center;
}

.text-size {
    font-size: 0.800rem !important;
}

.move-to-rightside {
    position: relative !important;
    right: 10px !important;
}

.container.container--app.pt-0 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will be helpful for you, but I actually wrote a component just recently for my vuetify based App to handle scrolling

```
<template>
    <div class="overflow-hidden">
        <div ref="$mainContent" class="overflow-y-auto" :style="{ 'max-height': maxHeight }">
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "NiceScroller",
    props: {
        sub: {
            type: String,
            default: () => "120px"
        }
    },
    computed: {
        maxHeight() {
            return `calc(100vh - ${this.sub})`;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Use it like

```
<nice-scroller sub="200px">
    .... content that will scroll
</nice-scroller>
```

`sub` is the amount of space for non-scrolling content (defaults to 120px in this code since that's what works for my App)

This is actually cut down to the basics of the real code - it's easy to add a "to top" like FAB that only appears once you've scrolled a certain amount for example.